# logical subsystem & physical subsystem

Tags: java, uml

I've done a google search on both of them, can't find much information.

I was wondering what is a logical subsystem and physical subsystem (in an object-oriented system)?

Also why would it be useful to keep the two separated?

Comment: Sounds like homework, and maybe teacher-defined terms. Logical subsystem would be all of your code that performs logic. Physical subsystem would be all of your code that deals with input/output. Separating them makes it so changes on one side don't interfere with changes on the other side.

Comment: @ProdigySim, it's not homework. I going through some old past test papers and I came across a question about logical subsystem & physical subsystem. There isn't much information about it on the net. Thanks for your answer. I'll see if I can expand on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical subsystem is how you would conceptually divide your subsystems. The concepts are important but physical locations don't matter.  So, logically the Model-View-Controller is divided into the 3 subsystems.

The physical subsystem is how your subsystems are deployed on the hardware. For instance, the Model and Controller can be located on a server PC while the View is located on a laptop that talks via Ethernet to the Model and Controller.

I would usually assign development responsibilities based on logical subsystems. Also, logical subsystems can span across multiple physical subsystems.